# Is it possible to see staged / unstaged as tree in EGit & Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I see the staged and unstaged dialogs, but all the files appears as one long list while I can't seem to have a way of sorting them.
Is it possible to see the staged / unstaged as tree ? (or any hierarchical structure ?)
BTW, is there a way of controlling this repository with command line (in windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the top-write of the Git Staging view there is a small down-arrow next to the minimize/maximize buttons.

If you click it you will see a few useful options including what you want.

Comment: "Tree" and "Compact Tree" modes were introduced back in EGit 3.1, see the screenshots in [release notes](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/3.1#Staging_View).